# Pressed list background is transparent - want it solid

Tags: android, android-layout

I use this as a backgroud for different `Views` that I use in my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_pressed_holo_light"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/listitem_border" />
</selector>
```

This works fine for all kind of list items, but when I have it above a `GoogleMap` it appears transparent when pressed:

[image]

I tried putting it inside a layout with a white background, but that surprisingly resulted in an all-white `View`. How can I have a solid 'holo-blue' background on the pressed state?

EDIT: This is the XML for the View shown in the pic (lower left):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/listitem_bg"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hallo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/zipcity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hallo" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the my try to have a solid bg:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/listitem_bg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/zipcity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hallo" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post the `xml` for the `View` that you are putting over the map?

Comment: Thanks, I'm away from my computer for an hour or two but as soon as I'm back I'll see what I can spot.

Comment: My bad, I didn't paste the whole thing. It's the android:background attribute within the first LinearLayout. Sorry about that.

Comment: Back earlier than expected. What colour is the text set to? (or is it just "default"?

Comment: It's default, I haven't set any sepcific color to it.

Comment: what happens if you et the background of the top LinearLayout to `@drawable/list_pressed_holo_light`, rather than going via the `selector` based `xml`?

Comment: Then the view has the same look as in the picture, even when not pressed.

Comment: "list_pressed_holo_light" can you post the contents of that file? Is it possible that the holo blue color referenced in that file has been set with an alpha?

Answer (score 0):

Without wishing to be silly, how about putting it in a layout with a solid black background?

Comment: Tried it (without much hope), the View is all black.

Answer (score 0):

try to add the one more item in your selector for focused state:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_pressed_holo_light"
          android:state_focused="true" />
```

- `state_pressed` is used when the user is pressing the item either through touch or a keyboard or a mouse
- `state_focused` is used if the item is marked focusable and it receives focus either through the user of a keyboard/dpad/trackball/etc. or if the item is focusable in touch mode

I'm always using both states - it works for me only if both of them are defined. The working example is [here](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/12/01/android-custom-button-layout-tutorial/)

Also ensure if both of your `@drawable`'s are correct